# error in registering hapi-swagger plugin in node.js

Tags: hapi.js

I am new to node.js development. I was just building the REST API using Hapi.js and Swagger plugin for learning purpose.

But while registering the hapi-swagger plugin in node.js ,it is giving some error of dependency.

Below is my code :

```
'use strict';

 const Hapi = require('hapi');
 const inert = require('inert');


  //creating server
  const server = new Hapi.Server();

  //connecting 
  server.connection({
     port:3000,
     host:'localhost'
   }
);


 //registering the swagger plugin (use for documentation and testing       purpose
server.register({
   register:require('hapi-swagger'),
   },
   function(err)
   {
    if(err)
        server.log(['error'],'hapi-swagger load error:'+err)
    else
        server.log(['start'],'hapi-swagger interface loaded');
}
);
```

Error showing is :

> /media/Tech/swagger_api/app.js:69
>           throw err;
>           ^

Error: Plugin hapi-swagger missing dependency inert in connection: http://localhost:3000
    at internals.Server._createCache.internals.Server.start.internals.Server.initialize.Items.parallel [as initialize] (/media/Tech/swagger_api/node_modules/hapi/lib/server.js:226:49)
    at internals.Server._createCache.internals.Server.start.Items.serial [as start] (/media/Tech/swagger_api/node_modules/hapi/lib/server.js:182:10)
    at Object. (/media/Tech/swagger_api/app.js:67:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:968:3

Comment: Did my answer work?

Answer (score 3):

You need to register inert and vision for hapi-swagger plugin to work, see this [line](https://github.com/glennjones/hapi-swagger/blob/master/lib/index.js#L145) showing it is a dependency.  This is a snippet to register plugins which has been taken from the projects readme.

```
const Hapi = require('hapi');
const Inert = require('inert');
const Vision = require('vision');
const HapiSwagger = require('hapi-swagger');
const Pack = require('./package');

const server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3000
});

const options = {
    info: {
        'title': 'Test API Documentation',
        'version': Pack.version,
    }
};

server.register([
    Inert,
    Vision,
   {
        'register': HapiSwagger,
        'options': options
}], (err) => {
    server.start( (err) => {
       if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
        }
    });
});

server.route(Routes);
```